# mediawiki 1.24 - no reset password page

Tags: mediawiki, reset-password

We have MediaWiki 1.24 installed on our intranet.

By default it suppose to have a special page called `PasswordReset`, but it doesn't.

I'm trying to enable such page, `grep`ed all files, looked everywhere, searched MediaWiki's help pages, searched google, what not. I can't find how to enable this page.

This page was suppose to be there since version 1.18.

How do I enable this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`$wgEnableEmail`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgEnableEmail), [`$wgPasswordResetRoutes`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgPasswordResetRoutes), [`AuthPlugin::allowPasswordChange()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/REL1_25/php/classAuthPlugin.html#a661aa70040f6a65edb1501a64733f929) (in case you are using an extension that implements AuthPlugin).